# Displaying information with mysql fetch array?

Tags: mysql, fetch

I'm trying to pull information from a table in mysql 'ptb_stats'. This is being pulled through 'user_id' specific so that each member of the site can only see their stats.

So far all that is happening is i'm getting the image echoed" on the page and the information being pulled just says array?

Any suggestions where im going wrong please?

Thanks

This is the function:

```
function get_stats() {
            global $connection;
            global $_SESSION;
            $query = "SELECT  s.location, s.nationality, s.hobbies, s.role, s.friends, s.height, s.weight
                        FROM ptb_stats s
                        WHERE user_id = \'$profile_id\'";



                        $stats_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($query, $connection);
            return $stats_set;
        }
```

This is the fetch array:

```
 <?php
        $stats_set = get_stats();

        while ($stats = mysql_fetch_array($stats_set)) {


            ?>
    <table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="13%"><?php echo "<img width=40px heigh=34px src=\"assets/img/icons/stats.png\"/>" ?></td>
      <td width="25%"><?php echo " $stats"?> </td>
      <td width="13%"><?php echo "<img width=40px heigh=34px src=\"assets/img/icons/stats.png\"/>" ?></td>
      <td width="25%"><?php echo " $stats"?> </td>
      <td width="13%"><?php echo "<img width=40px heigh=34px src=\"assets/img/icons/stats.png\"/>" ?></td>
      <td width="20%"><?php echo " $stats"?> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td height="36"><?php echo "<img width=40px heigh=34px src=\"assets/img/icons/stats.png\"/>" ?></td>
      <td><?php echo " $stats"?> </td>
      <td><?php echo "<img width=40px heigh=34px src=\"assets/img/icons/stats.png\"/>" ?></td>
      <td><?php echo " $stats"?> </td>
      <td><?php echo "<img width=40px heigh=34px src=\"assets/img/icons/stats.png\"/>" ?></td>
      <td><?php echo " $stats"?> </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
<?php
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: you didn't pass $profile_id to getStats function

Comment: ok sorry i'm new to sql. how do i do that?

Comment: and you are always echoing <?php echo " $stats"?> instead of <?php echo  $stats['location']?> etc

Comment: thanks but now when i change it i get this error message:                Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PTB1/includes/mod_profile/mod_profile.php on line 285

Comment: this is whats on line 285:  
  
  while ($stats = mysql_fetch_array($stats_set)) {

Comment: may be you are not getting proper resource object. use mysql_num_rows before while loop. fyi http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Answer (score 1):

$stats is an array with all your results. You need to define which values you want to display like that :

```
<?php echo $stats['location']; ?>
```

Futhermore, you should write your code like this way :

```
<?php
    $stats_set = get_stats();
    while ($stats = mysql_fetch_assoc($stats_set)) : 
?>

<table width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
    <td width="13%"><?php echo $stats['location']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**EDIT**

You need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array` (or specify `MYSQL_ASSOC`)
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: that didnt work :( still getting same error: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PTB1/includes/mod_profile/mod_profile.php on line 285

Comment: Code above is correct, you have a sql request problem : bad connection, sql syntax error, .... What is confirm_query? Check error using mysql_error after your mysql_query function : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: What do you mean by "is $stats_set"? After mysql_query() (if no error) $stats_set is a ressource, but when you are using in the mysql_fetch_assoc function it is not. Possibilities are : mysql error somwwhere or something bad happends to $stats_set in your confirm_query() function